# How do you open a new link in the default browser rather than the webview with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, browser, webview

The links always open up in the webview rather than the default internet browser for android

Also I am using an Iframe

Comment: attach your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [WebViewClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) for handle redirect page in WebView.

Just set `WebViewClient` in your `WebView`.

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

Create class for `WebViewClient` and you handle next page.

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
             Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
             startActivity(browserIntent);
            Log.d("URL", " : " + url);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks it works like a dream I added the new method too as shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) is depreceated: public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {